# Conservation laws in vacuum phase transition

Tags: conservation-laws, vacuum

Let's consider a bubble nucleation phase transition between different vacua via quantum tunnelling .For my understanding a particle must penetrate the potential barrier and find herself in an another energy state over the barrier. But this doesn't mean that the parent vacuum loses the particle ?This doesn't violate the conservation of energy laws?